# What is the difference between docker run and docker pull

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. Can anyone help me in understanding the difference between
 `docker run img_name` & `docker pull img_name`?

Do they work the same?

Comment: this link is useful to you to understand https://medium.com/@deepakshakya/beginners-guide-to-use-docker-build-run-push-and-pull-4a132c094d75

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`docker pull` pulls an image or a repository from a registry.

`docker run` runs a command in a new container.

They don't work the same, however, if you use `docker run` with an image that you haven't pulled yet, `docker run` will call `docker pull`:

```
$ docker rmi hello-world
Untagged: hello-world:latest
Untagged: hello-world@sha256:6f744a2005b12a704d2608d8070a494ad1145636eeb74a570c56b94d94ccdbfc
Deleted: sha256:fce289e99eb9bca977dae136fbe2a82b6b7d4c372474c9235adc1741675f587e
Deleted: sha256:af0b15c8625bb1938f1d7b17081031f649fd14e6b233688eea3c5483994a66a3
```

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6f744a2005b12a704d2608d8070a494ad1145636eeb74a570c56b94d94ccdbfc
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

…
```

Please see `docker help pull` and `docker help run` for more information.